# How to check if the record exist in xamarin

Tags: sqlite

```
public bool insertIntoTablePerson(Person person)
{
  try
  {
    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Persons.db")))
    {
      connection.Insert(person);
      return true;
    }
  } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
    Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should query the database and use the person's id to check if the person exist.

Answer (score 0):

generally, if the item already has a non-zero PK then it already exists

```
  if (item.ID != 0)
  {
    return database.UpdateAsync(item);
  }
  else {
    return database.InsertAsync(item);
  }
```

Comment: public bool insertIntoTablePerson(Person person)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Persons.db")))
                  
                {
              
                    connection.Insert(person);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }